# Connect analog sensor to PLC Omron CP1E-E30SDRA

Tags: sensor, plc, pressure

I have a Wisner pressure sensor 0-10 bar with output 4-20 mA. I want to connect it with PLC Omron CP1E-E30SDRA which this PLC doesn’t have any analog input pin. I want to use this sensor to maintain the pressure of water in the pipe so I have to send this sensor value to HMI but the PLC doesnt have any analog input to measure value of this sensor. How can I outsmart this case?

Comment: Welcome! Get a different PLC?

Comment: no, i dont have another PLC. do you know how to outsmart that case with the same PLC?

Comment: Add external circuitry to make your digital input an analog one, or external comparator.

Comment: Please edit your question to specify how many bits resolution you require in your analogue to digital conversion.

Answer (score 1):

The direct way should be to add an analog module, but also it is posible to use an analog to frecuency converting module. There are standard adapters for voltage/current (0/4..20 mA) signals to frecuency (may be 0..1 kHz), 24 Vdc. You can wire this adapter output to a digital input, and use a fast counter of PLC, and read the counter value in a fixed time cycle, it will proportional to analog current. Of course, programming will need some more effort.